# Entity Framework 6: How can I add new column to existing table and at the same time update view (add column) in same migration file

Tags: sql-server, view, table, alter-table, entity-framework

Example in the EF6 migration file `Up` method.

I wish to add a new column `B` in existing table `Country`.

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Country]
     ADD [B] INT DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL;")
```

Then I will need to add this new column `B` to it's `VCountry` view and I did the following:

```
DropView("VCountry")

Sql("CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VCountry]
         AS
         SELECT A, B FROM Country")
```

Everything looks good until I run the `Add-Migration XXX` command and the `Invalid column name 'B'.` prompt out.

What I trying to figure out is how to add the new column to the table and it's relevant view at the same migration file?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your method and it's working on my computer. Have you checked the column name having wrong spelling?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right!